# Are there Star Trek Species that are explicitly biologically incompatible?

Tags: star-trek, biology

We know that Klingon and Human DNA is compatible enough to reproduce (B'Elana Torres); same with Human and Vulcan DNA (Spock), and Cardassian and Bajoran DNA (Tora Ziyal).

Are there any examples of 2 humanoid species in Star Trek that are **explicitly noted in canon as NOT being biologically compatible**? (unable to produce a viable genetic offspring between each other *with* technological assistance as well)?

Comment: I have to VTC because this question is actually too broad to answer. There is an episode of *Enterprise* that posits some sort of hybrid creature descended from humans, Vulcans, and several other species, including some that Phlox had no point of reference for. We've seen a half-Betazed, half-human female impregnated with a fully-human child by a being composed of pure energy. We've see Trip Tucker impregnated, despite being a man, because *Enterprise* hired a *Futurama* writer. There is no adequate answer to this question.

Comment: @james that can be an answer - that there are no known limits (except ...).

Comment: In the TNG episode _[The Chase](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Chase_%28episode%29)_ it turned out we were all related. So I presume we're all compatible.

Comment: @Tony Meyer: That "except" covers a potentially huge amount of ground though. And there are non-humanoid organisms that are also apparently compatible with humans, such as the aforementioned Smizmar that tears Trip Tucker's loins asunder. So that renders Mr Lister's answer wrong too, unfortunately.

Comment: I agree with James, a canon list of compatible species would take ages to write up, and that's not taking into the account that Starfleet doctors have all kinds of clever treatments to make incompatible species compatible...

Comment: As @Richard said, Star Fleet doctors knows tricks to make incompatible species compatible. Jadzia Dax and Worf are the obvious examples.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hybrid

Comment: ROmulans are compatible with Klingons - See "Birthright Part 1"

Comment: Out of universe, Star Trek uses alien species to symbolize race and nationality. This allows Star Trek to make episodes about racism. Interspecies relationships are a big theme in Star Trek, and the Federation is a big melting pot.

Comment: @MrLister Except, not naturally, at least in one known case:  human/Vulcan isn't naturally possible (mentioned by Phloxx about Trip and T'Pol) unless they have help from some sort of technology/gene therapy

Comment: This is a good question, but those who have closed it do have a strong point: this is very broad. How many species have we seen across the many different series of this franchise? Hundreds, the low thousands? I'm not going to vote to reopen.

Comment: I agree w/ John O - what about odd combinations like Horta/Gorn? or Loki/Beale with an Orion slave girl?  Fun to come up with pairings, but...

Comment: I accidentally clicked while hovering over "Leave Closed." For the record, I planned to vote to reopen. Apologies, N. If someone out there wants to vote to leave closed, maybe don't and let my vote be that one? (I know, it's a stretch.)

Comment: Hold on though -- didn't Worf and Jadzia have to undergo some kind of gene-assisted fertilization hooplah to reproduce? They could not reproduce independently of technology as their species were not compatible. I may need to dig up the proper reference to this, but I believe Trill and Klingons can't mate without assistance.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - you can still vote to reopen on the question page, not in the review queue

Comment: I didn't get the impression that the "ovarian enzyme re-sequencing" was strictly necessary for Worf and Jadzia to conceive, but that it could potentially increase their chances.

Comment: I could have sworn their biology was regarded as 'incompatible' otherwise. I could be wrong on this.

Comment: A better example than Ziyal might be the baby from the Pah-Wraith Cult.  That was _definitely_ accidental, though I think it was left ambiguous about Ziyal.

Comment: Question as to the clarification:  With out without technological help?  I'm pretty sure a Horta and a human, or a human and Nacene, couldn't reproduce even with all the gene therapy and life support they could get.

Comment: @Izkata - I was originally  looking for without technological help, but it seems that would be *very* broad.  So I'm going to have to limit it to those which are completely biologically incompatible (ie, even with technological aid, breeding cannot occur)

Comment: Species 8472 is probably the only canonical answer... they mate is groups of somewhere around 5 different genders, and they live in fluidic space, making it all but certain they are biologically incompatible with every other species shown in Star Trek (except maybe Q...)  The Founders probably are also incompatible with "solids", at least of creating an offspring.