# How many alien species are compatible with humans?

Tags: star-trek, biology

In the various incarnations of *Star Trek* across the decades, there have been some important characters who are half-human, one of their parents being an alien:

- Mr Spock, from TOS, is half-human and half-Vulcan
- Deanna Troi, from TNG, is half human and half-Betazoid

Which got me wondering: how many such pairings are possible in the Star Trek universe?

### How many alien species are known to be compatible with humans?

---

For the pedants and nitpickers:

- "are known to be compatible" means "have produced offspring at least once"
- this is about reproductive, not sexual, compatibility: if Kirk had sex with an alien, it's not enough to qualify that species unless she bore him a child
- yes, this is a list question, but it's a finite and clearly scoped one.

Comment: If you believe TNG *The Chase*, then the answer could be: all of them.

Comment: Almost all of them naturally and pretty much all of them with some medical jiggery-pokery.

Comment: There is direct evidence of half-Klingon (Worf's mate), and half-Romulan. Not directly to the question, but there were also Klingon-Romulan children.  I don't recall if the Q who was raised on Earth was all Q or half-Q.

Comment: If you want a list of partial-human hybrid types that appear in canon, maybe the title should ask for that. Like Xantec said, there's a canon suggestion that pretty much any humanoid species should be compatible with humans.

Comment: Related: [Are there Star Trek Species that are explicitly biologically incompatible?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53366/are-there-star-trek-species-that-are-explicitly-biologically-incompatible)

Comment: most of the humanoid races need a medical hocus pocus is i remember, Vulcans specifically, which should mean romulans as well,

Comment: Cardassian-Bajoran hybrids were also possible.

Comment: Even with medical hocus pocus, nothing is guaranteed.  For a while Bashir didn't think a trill (trill host?) and a klingon could mate.

Comment: The term "alien species" includes way more than just humanoid species, so the reference to "The Chase" is misleading. I really doubt that humans could mate with Calamarain, Thasians, Organians, Metrons, Species 8472, Excalbians, Sheliak, various androids/robots, Borg, Nagilum, Guardian of Forever, Armus, etc., etc. Though perhaps some of the godlike beings could make it work.

Comment: Missed this one somehow...+1. :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to your examples, on screen there are:

- [K'Ehleyr](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/K'Ehleyr) and  [B'Elanna Torres](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B'Elanna_Torres): each half Human, half Klingon.
- [Naomi Wildman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Naomi_Wildman): half Human, half Ktarian.
- [Sela](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sela), who is half Romulan, half Human, and [Simon Tarses](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Tarses), who has a Romulan grandparent.
- [An unnamed boy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Denobulans) from a possible future in [Enterprise: E²](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/E%C2%B2_%28episode%29) who is depicted as a descendant of the Denobulan Phlox and a Human crew woman.
- [Karyn Archer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Karyn_Archer), also from E², who was descended from Human and Ikaaran stock, as well as from two unnamed species.
- [Daniel Kwan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Daniel_Kwan): half Human, half Napean.
- [Linnis Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Linnis_Paris), from a possible future in [Voyager: Before and After](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Before_and_After_%28episode%29): half Human, half Ocampa.
- [Bethany](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bethany), who had a Skagaran grandparent.
- A corpse from [Enterprise: Future Tense](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future_Tense_%28episode%29): half human, half Terrellian.
- [Yedrin Dax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yedrin_Dax) from a possible future in [Deep Space Nine: Children of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Time_(episode)): part human, part Trill host.

I have omitted several known descendants of the above individuals, as well as less prominent characters who provide examples of hybrids with the same species listed above.

There are several other borderline examples: melding of species which did not imply biological reproduction, and so forth. For a more exhaustive list of inter-species hybrids, consult the Memory Alpha [Hybrid](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hybrid) page, which I consulted heavily for this answer.

Comment: Saavik from *Star Trek II* was half Vulcan, half Romulan, according the the script.

Comment: In TNG *Angel One* humans are compatible with the natives of Angel One. However, I don't believe their species is ever mentioned and they look very human, so the 'Angel One'-ians could be human.

Comment: @Xantec Yeah, that's why I excluded them with the edge cases. Also, IIRC, the descendants are not shown.

Comment: Worf had a child, Alexandre, with a woman who was half Klingon and half human.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is the pilot of the starship from the future in *ENT* 'Future Tense'.  Phlox identifies that the pilot was human, but also had Vulcan and **Terrelian** DNA, showing that humans are probably also compatible with Terrelians.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cardassians and Bajorans
2. Kazon and Cardassians
3. Seska believed it was possible for a human and Cardassian to have a child.

Comment: It appears to me that the OP is asking about species that are compatible with humans, but your items 1 and 2 are compatible within themselves, if I understand correctly. Can you provide information for number 3?